WinForms ErrorProvider alternative at Avalonia
I'm currently in the process of migrating a Windows Forms application to Avalonia, and I'm struggling to find a suitable replacement for the built-in ErrorProvider control.
In WinForms, the ErrorProvider control provides a convenient way to indicate errors on a form, typically by displaying an error icon next to a control and displaying a tooltip with the error message when the user hovers over the icon.
After researching Avalonia controls, I couldn't find a built-in equivalent to the ErrorProvider control.
Can anyone suggest a suitable alternative in Avalonia that provides similar functionality? If not, could someone provide guidance on how to implement a custom control that achieves the same effect?"

I think you should use DataValidationErrors

As mentioned, Validation is the term you are looking for.  Avalonia supports the INotifyDataErrorInfo and ValidationAttribute options in .NET.  It also validates by exception, however this is a nasty code smell in my opinion, and I don't recommend it.
